# MySQL Error Number 2003 on windows 8

Tags: mysql

I have installed **MySQL Query browser 1.2.11 on my windows 8** machine, but i open **MySQL Query Browser** it show me error like bellow image

[image]

when i click on ping button it works fine for me. 
i google this problem and `disable my windows firewall` still it same error on open MySQL Query Browser

Comment: have you checked if the mysql server service is running?

Comment: Try using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)

Comment: `@bansi` mysql server service is stoped right now and when try to start it, it shows `Error 2: The System cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Please restart your WAMP, XAMPP or mysql hosted server and verify @bansi comment as well

Comment: check the windows event log. you can get more details there. mostly looks like a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server not starting mostly happens with permission issues or installation errors. Please check if there is any permission issues or try to reinstall mysql.

Please check the following link for more info [Can't connect to [local] MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Error No. 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (or some other host)

simply means that connection is not possible for one of the following (or similar) reasons:

- There is no MySQL server running at the specified host
- Connection to the MySQL server is not allowed using TCP-IP. Check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini on Windows, my.cnf on Unix/Linux). It shall be commented out like '#skip-networking'. If it is not commented out, then do it and restart the MySQL server for the change to take effect. Needs to connect using TCP-IP.
- Some networking issue prevents connection. It could be a network malconfiguration or a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occur when mysql service get stopped.

In Windows OS:
Right click on my computer>> manage>>services and application>>services

Then search for mysql. Right click on mysql then properties from there select "start up type" after that click on start.

Now login to your mysql. It should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

seems like service went down.

please start the service if it stopped .

## service mysqld start

Answer (score 0):

go to start-> run-> services.msc

in this search for MySQL right click and 'start'...

now you can login again...Query Browser will start again...